# Android Device Screen Mirroring Using Nodejs/Angular/Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I mirror the screen of the Android Device into Nodejs?

Currently, I want NodeJS to detect the android device mirror its screen, and pass to angular through the socket.

Any help on this?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Amit I want to set up a project in angular that is connected to nodejs. In node js whenever I connect any android device it will detect it mirror its screen and pass it to Angular through the socket.

Till now I am not able to find anything in node js which will mirror the android screen.